# Removing numbers from string while keeping alphanumeric words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove numeric values without losing numbers that are part of alphanumeric words from a string.

```
String = "Jobid JD123 has been abended with code 346"

Result = "Jobid JD123 has been abended with code"
```

I am using the following code:

```
result = ''.join([i for i in String if not i.isdigit()])
```

which gives me the result as '`Jobid JD has been abended with code`'

Is there anyway we can remove the words that only contain digits, while retaining those that contain a mix of letters and digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex to find runs of one or more digits `\d+` between two word boundaries `\b`, and replace them with nothing.

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "Jobid JD123 has been abended with code 346"
>>> re.sub(r"\b\d+\b", "", string).strip()
'Jobid JD123 has been abended with code'
```

Note that the regex doesn't get rid of the trailing space (between `"code"` and the digits), so you need to `strip()` the result of the `re.sub()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.isnumeric()` to remove any word that doesn't only contain numbers:

```py
s = "Jobid JD123 has been abended with code 346"
result = ' '.join(c for c in s.split() if not c.isnumeric())
print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
Jobid JD123 has been abended with code
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` the string into words and check if the entire word is numerical

```
Result = " ".join(word for word in String.split() if not word.isnumeric())

>>> Result
'Jobid JD123 has been abended with code'
```